# dhclient wlan0 gets stuck

Tags: wireless, dhclient

I setted the password/ssid using `sudo iwconfig wlan0 essid *ssid* key *password*` without any errors, but then when I try using `sudo dhclient wlan0` it goes forever and never stops.

I tried using `sudo iw dev wlan0 scan | grep SSID` and it listed everything right wich means the network is avaliable.

Comment: "iwconfig key" is for WEP encryption. Is that what you have? In any event, it will not work at all if Network Manager is working. Is it?